# perl subroutine

Tags: perl, subroutine

I am having trouble with execution of my perl subroutines.
Here is the definition:

```
sub primer{
     print STDERR "primer is $_[0]\n";
    $primer=$_[0];
   if ($_[0]=~/ATTACCGC/){
           mkdir ("Primer1") || die "Unable to create directory <$!>\n";
           open OUTFILE1,">","Primer1/lt450";
           open OUTFILE2,">","Primer1/no_primer_lt450";
           open REPORT,">","Primer1/Report";
           &primer_analysis('ATTACCGC');}

           if ($_[0]=~/CCGTCAATTC[AC]/){
           mkdir ("Primer2") || die "Unable to create directory <$!>\n";
           open OUTFILE1,">","Primer2/lt450";
           open OUTFILE2,">","Primer2/no_primer_lt450";
            open REPORT,">","Primer2/Report";
           &primer_analysis('CCGTCAATTC[AC]');}
```

Here is part of another subroutine that should be invoked by above:

```
sub primer_analysis{
     $primer=$_[0];
    while ($line = <INFILE>){
         if ($line =~ /^>/) {
             $header = $line;
            $headcnt++;}
         if ($line !~/^>/){
         $seq = $line;
          chomp($seq);
        if (length($seq)<450 && $seq=~/^$primer/){
            $len_450=length($seq);
            $TB_450=$len_450+$TB_450;
               $cnt450++;
              print OUTFILE1 "$header";
              print OUTFILE1 "$seq\n";}}
```

And following is calling the function:

```
&primer('ATTACCGC');
&primer('CCGTCAATTC[AC]');
```

problem is that when I run the program only the Primer1 gets executed i.e. directories and data is properly created, however, nothing happens to Primer2.
Any ideas why only one part of the function is getting executed? 
Thanks

Comment: You are making things difficult for yourself by not indenting your code properly, using lots of (only?) global variables, repeating code unnecessarily and not using logic well (e.g. `if (/^>/) .... if (!/^>/)` is really `if (...) else`.) If you are not using strict and warnings, I strongly recommend that you do so.

Comment: Hi, on the contrary, the indentation is perfect in the code, I am not not able to get the hang of it while posting it here. Agreed to the redundancy, I have corrected that. I do not use too much of strict, and diagnostics and warning is always a must for me.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "too much of strict", but I assume you are saying you do not use it, which is a big mistake. Using strict actually saves time and effort.

Comment: yes, you are correct. I do not use strict. As a good practice I should use it, but so far, I have tried best to use names properly and have paid attention to the scope of the vars. But may be its time I should start use strict as line of code keep increasing......

Comment: Instead of repetitive, literal values, define a constant or a variable and use that; e.g. $primer_1 = q(Primer1).  Get in the habit of **always** using the strict pragma too.  You will be amply rewarded in decreased debugging time fixing "stupid" mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

the characters `[]` are special characters in regular expressions. You need to escape them in sub primer by writing `CCGTCAATTC\[AC\]`, or simply use the `eq` string comparison. As is, your second if is failing because the literal `[` in your primer does not match the `[AC]` character class.

Comment: Great...I thought of that as well...and I did that. However, the files get created, but no data in them.

Comment: You can also use the `\Q .. \E` to match literal characters inside the regex. E.g. `/\QCCGTCAATTC[AC]\E/`

Comment: okay. got the problem solved. I was not opening the file to be read again. The call to open the file was made only once. Thanks for helping with the regex. Must appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

General advice:

1. Use strict; use warnings;
2. Consider using shift instead of $_[0], i.e.

   ```
   $primer = shift;
       if $primer =~ /ATTACCGC/){ ..... etc.
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   $primer=$_[0];
       if ($_[0]=~/ATTACCGC/){
   ```

   ...and then use $primer instead of $_[0] in your function.
3. [Lexical filehandles](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) are recommended.
4. Don't use the ampersand to call your functions.